# S. Chowla real quadratic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ be a real quadratic fields. S. Chowla conjectured that if $d=4m^2+1$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ then there is exactly 6 real quadratic fields which has class number one. Hideo Yokoi proved this conjecture (almost!). Then the natural question arises: What can be said about similar real quadratic fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a^2m^2+1})$ for $a \not = 2$ and $m$ a integers?
I am looking for suitable reference for this question? Can someone suggest reference for this question?

Comment: Don't you mean $a \not = 2$?

Comment: Not only $a \ne 2$, but $a = 1$. And he probably googled "New York mining desaster" instead of "Chowla real quadratic".

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

The conjectures of Chowla and Yokoi were proved by Biró (2003). The state-of-the-art of this problem is contained in the following [preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.05644) by Biró and Lapkova (2015).

Comment: The paper of Biró and Lapkova was published as: Acta Arith. 172 (2016), no. 2, 117–131. https://eudml.org/doc/279595